# Gebrauch vs. Verwendung

Tags: meaning, difference

What is the difference in meaning in between *Gebrauch* and *Verwendung*?  At [context.reverso.net](https://context.reverso.net) they seem to mean the same.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference in meaning. They do mean the same.

Comment: They are mainly synonyms, but there are cases where you can use "Verwendung" but not "Gebrauch", e.g. "*Verwendung der Steuergelder*", but not "Gebrauch der Steuergelder". (I don't know if there are examples for the opposite case.)

Comment: @Bodo: You can compare the various uses of the words in the [DWDS usage database](https://www.dwds.de/wp/?q=Gebrauch&comp-method=diff&comp=Verwendung&pos=2&minstat=0&minfreq=5&by=logDice&limit=20&view=table). My impression is that if you're using a tool or weapon then it's *Gebrauch*, and if it's something more abstract then it's *Verwendung*.

Comment: @RDBury Then my impression is that you can use both *Gebrauch*  and *Verwendung*  for specific real things and only *Verwendung* for more abstract things.

Comment: There are differences in idiomatics, but not in meaning. That is, there are cases where only one of them is commonly used, but it's always possible to substitute the other one without changing the meaning. You _can_ say "Gebrauch der Steuergelder" or "Verwendung des Werkzeugs", it's not wrong, just a bit unusual.